# componentWillReceiveProps hooks equivalent

Tags: react-hooks

I'm trying to get the componentWillReceiveProps hooks equivalent:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
if(newProps.errors){
this.setState({errors:newProps.errors})
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i think you should use useEffect in react hooks its better to go with hooks